# Html exist A tab character before a character

Tags: php, html

I am printing some names in PHP. However is always exist a tab character at the begin and end of string . How can I remove the tab character. Here is my code, it still cannot remove the extra tab.

```
<strong>
    <?php 
       for ($i=0;$i <count($countrys);$i++){
             $country = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu', ' ', $countrys[$i]);
             $country = trim($country);
             echo $country;
                  if ($i != count($countrys)-1){
                    echo ', ';
                  }
          }
    ?>
</strong>
```

The outcome of the printing is like this.

```
    "  China, England, USA   "
```

Comment: did you try `trim()`? You could use `\t`

Comment: already have trim() in the code

Comment: Did you try the escape character `\t`

Comment: Share `$countrys` data?

Comment: I made a dummy array `$countrys = ['United States', 'Russia', 'France', 'Japan']` and could not re-create the issue. Knowing the value of `$countrys` would be helpful as mentioned above.

Comment: Array ( [0] => China [1] => England [2] => Trinidad and Tobago [3] => USA )

Comment: Does the string contain `&nbsp;` or something similar? This is an HTML entity that is written as text, but converted to a space character when rendered in the DOM.

Comment: As it is embedded in html, I am doubting the <php open tag and ?> close tag created the tab before and after the strings.

Comment: I found it is strange, in developer tools, I inspect the countrys print by PHP. I found that at the begining, it have ^I^I at the begin of printing and at the end of printing.

Comment: <strong><?php 
$countrys = ['a','v'];
for ($i=0;$i<count($countrys);$i++){
  $country = $countrys[$i];
  echo $country;
  if ($i != count($countrys)-1){
    echo ', ';
  }
}
?></strong>

Maybe the same row of html tag can solve it?

Comment: @StanleyCheung how can I mark your comment as answer.

Comment: Let me answer it again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful the space between html Tag and php code, browser will read the space between html tag and php echo

So just render it in one row

```
<strong><?php $countrys = ['a','v']; for ($i=0;$i<count($countrys);$i++){ $country = $countrys[$i]; echo $country; if ($i != count($countrys)-1){ echo ', '; } } ?></strong>
```

You can simply to check your raw html source after rendering to prevent unexpected space or row